# discover which Eclipse projects are opened

Tags: eclipse, maven, project

Is there any way to discover programatically (but not in PDE code) which eclipse projects are opened?

I was hoping that would exist a .metadata anywhere telling me that, but couldn't find any non binary data.

The closer I got was something like:

"$WORKSPACE.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/%s/org.eclipse.jdt.core/state.dat" where %s refers to the project name

I think m2eclipse uses that guy for some kind of control, because on a m2project this file gets removed as soon as the projects build.

Also, i found some information on .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/workingsets.xml but none of them give me the full info I was hoping to find.

Does anyone knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying on eclipse 3.7.

On eclipse 4.3 , at least, its possible to parse $WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/workingsets.xml and look up whether the desired project has a factoryID="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PersistableJavaElementFactory", meaning it is opened.

I Didn't try this on 4.2 tough, maybe it works there as well.

Answer (score -1):

To do it "programmatically", you call the APIs from the org.eclipse.core.resources plug-in.  Otherwise, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: ok. I told, i don't want to do it in PDE code. I'm trying to do it on a maven plugin (maven eclipse plugin). does it look wrong to you?